# Want to echo good error message in case of linux command failed

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a function in bash so that when any command fails, It will print a nice error message, I tried this

```
#!/bin/bash
msg()
{
  if echo $? > 0 ; then
    echo "==> Something wrong happened. Please see /var/log/install.log"
  else
    echo "==> Done"
  fi
}
```

But when I tried to use them in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
msg()
{
  if echo $? > 0 ; then
    echo "==> Something wrong happened. Please see /var/log/install.log"
  else
    echo "==> Done"
  fi
}

mkdir vcvcxvcxv
msg
```

Then I ran this on terminal

```
$ bash check 
mkdir: vcvcxvcxv: File exists
==> Something wrong happened, Please see /var/log/install.log
```

I got same output whatever. But I suppose to get the "Done" message when my command succeeds. Is there any help in this regard?

Comment: Uh... your command failed...

Comment: Yeah but i got same error message even command run successfully, Which i dont expect..

Comment: The really sad part is that it seems to be the norm amongst commercial vendors to assign the installation script to their most junior personnel with no guidance whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
if echo $? > 0
```

does not do *anything* you want it to.

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
```

Comment: Waw, Awesome, Got desired answer, Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to erase the file called "0".

Comment: I didnt understand, What are you trying to say here, can you explain, I will going to use multiple linux commands in same bash script..

Comment: He is saying `echo > 0` is a redirection; a file called `0` Is created and the output of `echo` (a single newline) is written to it.

Comment: This answer will serve your purpose. Just FYI: pseudo code `$? > 0` translates to `[ $? -gt 0 ]`... & `[ $? -ne 0 ]` in the answer is logically equivalent to `$? != 0`...

Answer (score 1):

Although you got your immediate problem fixed already, your code isn't very idiomatic, and violates some fundamental shell scripting principles.

- Errors should produce an error status
- Error messages should go to standard error
- Don't be needlessly verbose

So the simplest fix is really

```
mkdir vcvcxvcxv || exit
```

since `mkdir` already produces an error message on stderr, and `exit` will propagate the value of `$?` to the calling process.

Incidentally, you can get much the same effect with `set -e` but it is slightly cumbersome to use for the newcomer.

If you want the "helpful" error message, perhaps this;

```
death () {
    rc=$?
    echo "$0: see /var/log/install.log" >&2
    exit $rc
}

mkdir vcvcxvcxv || death
echo "$0: done." >&2
```

would be closer to what you really need. Notice how the status messages are redirected to standard error (and each has the name of the script, so you can see what's causing the failure when you have scripts calling scripts calling scripts, etc) and the exit status is naturally propagated to the caller, and the entire script aborted, in the case of a fatal error. Also, the flow of the main script becomes more natural as it grows;

```
something || death
additional thing || death
final thing || death
echo "$0: done." >&2
```

(Of course, if failure means death always, you actually want `set -e`.)